# Copy Items Between Two EWS Servers - Powershell

Tags: powershell, exchangewebservices

I'm Trying to Get Into EWS, my Goal is to copy Data between Two Exchange Mailbox's in two different locations.

I'm Binding Two Inbox Folders, each in diffrent mailbox
Then i Get the items in the Source inbox folder and try to copy this items to the destination inbox folder, here's the code.

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Exchange\Web Services\2.0\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll"  

## Remote Connection ##

$MailboxName="User@Domain.com"
$ExchangeVersion = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeVersion]::Exchange2007_SP1
$Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WebCredentials("User","Password","Domain")
$exchService = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService($ExchangeVersion)
$exchService.Credentials = $Credentials

$exchService.Url = "https://Domain.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx"

## Bind Remote Inbox Folder

$FolderName="Inbox" 
$folderid= new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::$FolderName,$MailboxName)  
$MailFolder = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($exchservice,$folderid)

## Local Connection ##

$LocalMailboxName = "LocalUser@Domain.local"
$LocalExchangeVersion = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeVersion]::Exchange2010_SP2
$LocalExchService = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService($LocalExchangeVersion)
$LocalExchService.UseDefaultCredentials = $true
$LocalExchService.AutodiscoverUrl($LocalMailboxName)
$LocalExchService.ImpersonatedUserId = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ImpersonatedUserId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ConnectingIdType]::SmtpAddress, $LocalMailboxName) 
$LocalFolderName="Inbox" 
$Localfolderid= new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::$LocalFolderName,$LocalMailboxName)  
$LocalMailFolder = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($LocalExchService,$Localfolderid)

## Get the items of the source mailbox "Inbox"

$ivItemView =  New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemView(100)
$fiItems = $exchservice.FindItems($MailFolder.id,$ivItemView)

## The Copy Section

foreach ($item in $fiItems) 
{
$item.Copy($LocalMailFolder.Id)
}
```

Then I get This Error:

```
Exception calling "Copy" with "1" argument(s): "No mailbox with such guid."
At line:1 char:30
+ foreach ($item in $fiItems) {$item.Copy($LocalMailFolder.Id)}
+                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ServiceResponseException
```

Appreciate any help, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use copy to copy mails between Exchange Services, the error simply means that the remote service does not know the local folder id - because that folder(with that ID) does not exist on the remote service.

You need to load the item, create a NEW item in your local folder, copy all properties from the old item to the new one, then save the new item.

As I do not know Powershell, here a C# listing that should get you started, instead of:

```
foreach ($item in $fiItems) 
{
$item.Copy($LocalMailFolder.Id)
}
```

->

```
foreach (var remoteItem in fiItems) 
{ 
   var localItem = new Item(LocalExchService); 
   localItem.Subject = remoteItem.Subject;
   localItem.Body = remoteItem.Body;
   // ... and so on. need to cast to the correct type, to access ALL properties, too.
   localItem.Save(LocalMailFolder);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, can you give some more info about this, if possible in powershell terms, or c#

Comment: Thanks, I copied all the properties and ran it, when i do the $LocalItem.Save($LocalFolderID) i get this error: Exception calling "Save" with "1" argument(s): "EmailAddress or ItemId must be included in the request."
At line:1 char:1
+ $NewItem.save($Localfolderid)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ServiceResponseException

Comment: btw: i use this to create the item object: $LocalItem = New-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage($LocalExchService)

Comment: Did you set properties (here most likely an emailaddress) to an empty string? EWS hates that.